# Angular 6 - Sonarqube coverage report is always 0 but karma shows coverage

Tags: angular, typescript, sonarqube, code-coverage

I am trying to set up sonarqube for my angular 6 project. I have 5 basic tests that are running fine and the karma coverage report is given below

```
Chrome 92.0.4515 (Windows 10.0.0): Executed 5 of 5 SUCCESS (0.807 secs / 0.868 secs)

=============================== Coverage summary ===============================
Statements   : 29.65% ( 282/951 )
Branches     : 23.37% ( 115/492 )
Functions    : 16.84% ( 32/190 )
Lines        : 28.2% ( 258/915 )
================================================================================
```

I set up sonarqube locally to see the coverage report but it gives coverage as 0% always.

As karma shows some coverage, I expect sonar coverage should be in some minor numbers atleast.

sonar-project.properties file

```
sonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000
sonar.login=admin
sonar.password=admin123
sonar.projectKey=myproject:ui
sonar.projectName=Sample App
sonar.projectVersion=0.0.0
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
sonar.sources=src
sonar.exclusions=**/node_modules/**
sonar.tests=src
sonar.test.inclusions=**/*.spec.ts
sonar.typescript.lcov.reportPaths=coverage/myproject/lcov.info
```

package.json snippet

```
"scripts": {
    "sonar": "sonar-scanner"
  },
"devDependencies": {
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.3.0",
    "sonar-scanner": "^3.1.0",
  }
```

lcov.info file is present under src/coverage/myproject/lcov.info

I had run `npm run sonar` and I could see the coverage in sonarqube as 0.0 %

Please help me to fix the issue

Comment: why are you excluding all spec files ?

Comment: I thought `sonar.exclusions` only for code quality and as I have included specs in test inclusions it should work.

Comment: Updated `sonar.exclusions=**/node_modules/**,src/assets/**, **/*.e2e.ts, **/environments/**/*, **/*.routes.ts, **/main.ts,**/polyfills.ts`  still seeing the same results

Comment: Are you sure you are meant to exclude the files like that? Is that not excluding them from sonar in general?

Maybe this helps, where the spec files are only excluded for coverage on themselves: https://community.sonarsource.com/t/setting-sonar-scanner-exclusions/12222

Comment: Hmm, I was not sure about that and that can be changed to exclude only node modules `sonar.exclusions=**/node_modules/**`, still nothing has changed

Comment: I have updated my post with the latest `sonar-project.properties `

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
sonar.typescript.lcov.reportPaths=coverage/myproject/lcov.info
```

use

```
sonar.javascript.lcov.reportPaths=coverage/myproject/lcov.info.
```

Then run `sonar-scanner` or `npm run sonar`. it will work fine.